# Batch file string concatenation

Tags: string, batch-file

Why is this string not concatenating?

```
@echo off
set NUM_NODES=4
set ENSEMBLE=127.0.0.1:2181

for /l %%x in (2, 1, %NUM_NODES%) do (
    echo %%x
   set ENSEMBLE=%ENSEMBLE%,127.0.0.1:2%%x81
)
echo ensemble: %ENSEMBLES%
```

OUTPUT:

```
2
3
4
ensemble: 127.0.0.1:2181,127.0.0.1:2481
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in batch files variables are expanded when a command is *parsed*, not immediately prior to its execution. If you want the latter behaviour, you need to use delayed expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
set NUM_NODES=4
set ENSEMBLE=127.0.0.1:2181

for /l %%x in (2, 1, %NUM_NODES%) do (
    echo %%x
   set ENSEMBLE=!ENSEMBLE!,127.0.0.1:2%%x81
)
echo ensemble: %ENSEMBLES%
```

`help set` contains a lengthy description and exactly your example.

Answer (score 0):

Both the original example and the answer contain the same typo, adding an S to the end of the variable in the ECHO statement, so neither example as it appears produces any output from the variable.