# Scraping all file names with their creation and modification date from a directory

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am running this bat script, `fileNames.bat > print.txt`, to get all file Names.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
:: Load the file path "array"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /s /b^|findstr /n "^"') do (
  set "file.%%A=%%B"
  set "file.count=%%A"
)

:: Access the values
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /l %%N in (1 1 %file.count%) do echo !file.%%N!
```

However, I would also like to get in the output the `creation` and `modification date` for each file path.

My current output looks like that:

```
C:\Programs\FirefoxPortable\fileNames.bat 
C:\Programs\FirefoxPortable\Firefox
C:\Programs\FirefoxPortable\print.txt
C:\Programs\FirefoxPortable\Firefox\App
C:\Programs\FirefoxPortable\Firefox\Data
```

Any suggestions, how to get the `creation` and `modification date` next to each file path?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Look into string concatenation.  [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15137598/batch-file-string-concatenation) question for details.

Comment: Thx for your answer! Any recommendations how to get the `creation and modification` date from the file? I would appreciate an example!

Comment: type `dir /?` and check out `/T` switch...

Comment: `%%~tB` Display the (modification) date/time of `%%B`; see http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html or read _entire_ `for /?`. Retrieving creation date needs a more sophisticated approach.

Answer (score 1):

Following `.bat` script produces a `csv`-like output with `|` vertical line delimited values of next pattern:

```
type|creation datetime|modification datetime|full path|
```

Delayed expansion kept *disabled* as there are file names containig `!` exclamation mark(s): see the `call set` trick in [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) and in [CALLing internal commands](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html).
Note that retrieving *creation* date and time discriminates between folders and files.
**`%%G` tokenization could vary for another regional settings!**

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL enableextensions disableDelayedExpansion
:: Set the working directory and store the previous folder/path
pushd d:\test
:: Load the file path "array"
set "file.count=0"
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('dir /s /b^|findstr /n "^"') do (
  set "file.%%A=%%B"
  set "file.count=%%A"
)
:: Restore path/folder most recently stored by the PUSHD command
popd 

:: Access the values (keep )
set /A "ii=0"
:loop
if %ii% GEQ %file.count% goto :loopend
set /A "ii+=1"
call set "file.curr=%%file.%ii%%%"
if exist "%file.curr%\" (
  rem folder
  for %%g in ("%file.curr%") do (
    set "defined="
    for /F "skip=5 tokens=1,2" %%G in ('
      dir /-c /a:d /t:C "%file.curr%"
      ') do (
          if not defined defined (
            echo FLDR^|%%G %%H^|%%~tg^|%file.curr%^|
            set "defined=%%~tg %%G %%H"
          )
    )
  )
) else (
  rem file
  for %%g in ("%file.curr%") do (
    set "defined="
    for /F "skip=5 tokens=1,2" %%G in ('
      dir /-c /a:-d /t:C "%file.curr%"
      ') do (
          if not defined defined (
            echo FILE^|%%G %%H^|%%~tg^|%file.curr%^|
            set "defined=%%~tg %%G %%H"
          )
    )
  )
)
goto :loop
:loopend
ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

My current **output** looks as follows (reduced to reasonable size):

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31824138.bat
FILE|26.07.2015 11:02|26.07.2015 11:02|d:\test\File N.txt|
FLDR|24.07.2015 20:21|05.08.2015 18:44|d:\test\set|
FILE|24.07.2015 20:23|24.07.2015 20:23|d:\test\set\hklm.txt|
FILE|24.07.2015 20:26|24.07.2015 20:30|d:\test\set\regs.txt|
FILE|05.08.2015 18:44|05.08.2015 18:45|d:\test\set\t!exclam!t.txt|

==>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have one final question, how can the current file size be added to your script? Appreciate your reply!

Comment: @mrquad `%%~zg` displays the **file size** of `%%g` (only use for _file_; don't use for _folder_ as it's another _non-trivial_ task). I repeat: read http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html or read _entire_ `for /?`.